# Merge 1 dataframe to multiple dataframes in list- R

Tags: c, r, merge, lapply

EDITED TO ADD DATAFRAME EXAMPLE: 
I have a list of ten dataframes (DFList). I have one dataframe (DFMain) I want to merge to each of them (DFList) in an lapply function. They share the Column1, named Column1, which is the column I am merging by. It works for the first dataframe in the list, but ignores the rest of them. What am I missing? Thanks!

Example of dataframe in list (DFList has 10 of these type of dataframes)

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
tulip   1   0.2
rose    2   0.3
apple   3   0.4
tree    4   0.5
forest  5   0.6
orange  6   0.7
purple  7   0.8
green   8   0.9
```

Example of DFMain:

```
Column1 Column2
tulip   10
rose    11
apple   12
tree    13
forest  14
orange  15
```

Merge Currently:

```
mymerge<-function(x){
    x<- merge(x, DFMain, by.x=c("Column1"), by.y=("Column1"), all.x=TRUE);
};

finishedmerge<-lapply(DFList, mymerge);
```

Expected output would be for every dataframe in list. Currently it only does this for the FIRST dataframe in the list.

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column2
tulip   1   0.2 10
rose    2   0.3 11
apple   3   0.4 12
tree    4   0.5 13
forest  5   0.6 14
orange  6   0.7 15
purple  7   0.8 NA
green   8   0.9 NA
```

Comment: Can you please provide minimal representative sample data and your expected output? You should be able to achieve this with a combination of `Reduce` and `merge`; it's easier to help with a specific example.

Comment: Thank you, added an example.